# Correct implementation of time based storage of objects

Tags: java, android, serialization, calendar

For a given task, I should store an object while keeping track of the time of its creation at least per day.

The easiest solution I could find is to use Calendar to set day of year based on time stamp of objects creation.

Here is the object in a simple form:

```
public class PhysicalActivity implements Serializable {

    private long mTimestamp;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonthOfYear;
    private int mWeekOfYear;
    private int mWeekOfMonth;
    private int mDayOfYear;
    private int mDayOfMonth;
    private int mDayOfWeek;

    public PhysicalActivity(long timestamp){
        mTimestamp = timestamp;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(mTimestamp);
        c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonthOfYear = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mWeekOfYear = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        mWeekOfMonth = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        mDayOfYear = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        mDayOfMonth = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mDayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
   }

   //Getters for all members...

}
```

**Then I have this object that holds all instances in an `List<PhysicalActivity>`:**

```
public class PhysicalActivityHolder implements Serializable {

    private long mCreationTimestamp;
    private long mLastUpdateTimestamp;
    private List<PhysicalActivity> mList;

    public PhysicalActivityHolder(long creationTimestamp) {
        mCreationTimestamp = creationTimestamp;

        if(mList == null) {
            mList = new ArrayList<PhysicalActivity>();
        }
    }

    public void addPhysicalActivity(PhysicalActivity pa){
        if(mList == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("List is null");
        } else {
            mList.add(pa);
        }
    }

    public List<PhysicalActivity> getPhysicalActivitiesForDayOfYear(int dayOfYear) {
        List<PhysicalActivity> activities = null;
        for(PhysicalActivity p : mList) {
            if(p.getDayOfYear() == dayOfYear){
                activities.add(p);
            }
        }
        return activities;
    } 

    //Some similar methods for getting list by month of year, week of year...etc...
}
```

Then whenever there is a new `PhysicalActivity` instance is coming, I read the `PhysicalACtivityHolder` from disk (deserialize), add the new instance to the `List<>` and then save (serialize) the `Holder` object again to the disk.

I hope that you got my point by now. I am afraid this is not going to be a good solution. one of the problems is what if the device's timestamps changes? then the whole idea will be ruined.

I would love to know how would you implement such task? what could be the better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, while not related to the timestamp issue, an [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) would seem like a much more appropriate medium to store this information. In particular:

- You don't need to serialize and deserialize the whole collection every time.
- You don't need to keep the whole collection in memory.
- You can add, remove, or update single events.
- You can easily query by year, month, &c using SQL SELECT statements.

About the "timestamp changing" part (unless you have an external, trusted data source for the time, such as a server), yes, the device's date or time may be manually changed. However, how big of a problem would that be? This data wouldn't seem to be *critically* dependent on having the exact time.